# Transferring text from one form to another form

Tags: vb.net, forms, textbox, vb.net-2010

I'm having a hard time transferring the text from the Textbox4 in StudentInfo form to the Textbox in Categories form. I've done the basic Textbox.Text = Categories.Textbox.Text code (I've reversed it also by coding on Categories_Load event), but still, I can't display the text.

Can anyone help me here?

PS: I've also done the Public Property code. AND by the way, the studentinfo form has still to jump to 2 forms before it reaches the categories form.

My code in a button in studentinfo (confirm & continue)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox4.Text = Categories.yrlvlhere.Text

End Sub
```

In categories:

```
Private Sub Categories_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.yrlvlhere.Text = StudentInfo.TextBox4.Text
End Sub
```

yrlvlhere is the name of the textbox I will be changing texts with.

A visual representation of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: We cant tell you want you did wrong in *code* without seeing the *code*.  Please read [asl], the [faq] and take the [tour]

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, I forgot to attach the pastebin link of the code. 
Categories.vb - http://pastebin.com/PeG1Se26
StudentInfo.vb - http://pastebin.com/bU4JCKsQ

Comment: Please read [Ask] and the [FAQ] and take the [Tour].  Code needs to be in the question, not linked to somewhere else.  Make it *easy* for someone to help you - dont send them elsewhere.  Dont post the entire app - just a [MCVE]

Comment: Thank you sir, I have already edited my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBox4.Text = Categories.yrlvlhere.Text
```

With this you are overwriting the text from `TextBox4` in `StudentInfo` with the then empty text from `yrlvlhere` in `Categories`.
Just switch the sides of the assignment.

```
Categories.yrlvlhere.Text = TextBox4.Text
```